# cancellation in numpy array operation including a scalar

Tags: python, numpy, numeric, rounding, floating-accuracy

I'm using NumPy version 1.7.1.
Now I came across a strange cancellation I don't understand:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([ 883,  931,  874], dtype=np.float32)
```

Mathematically `a+0.1-a` should be `0.1`. 
Now let's calculate the value of 
this expression and absolute and relative error:

```
>>> a+0.1-a
array([ 0.09997559,  0.09997559,  0.09997559], dtype=float32)
>>> (a+0.1-a)-0.1
array([ -2.44155526e-05,  -2.44155526e-05,  -2.44155526e-05], dtype=float32)
>>> ((a+0.1-a)-0.1) / 0.1
array([-0.00024416, -0.00024416, -0.00024416], dtype=float32)
```

First question: This is a quite high absolute and relative error, this is just *catastrophic cancellation*, isn't it?

Second question: When I use an array instead of the scalar, NumPy is able to calculate with much more precision, see the relative error:

```
>>> a+np.array((0.1,)*3)-a
array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1])
>>> (a+np.array((0.1,)*3)-a)-0.1
array([  2.27318164e-14,   2.27318164e-14,   2.27318164e-14])
```

This is just the numerical representation of `0.1` I guess.

But why is NumPy not able to handle this the same way if a scalar is used instead of an array as in `a+0.1-a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use double precision the scenario changes. What you are getting is expected for single precision (`np.float32`):

```
a = np.array([ 883,  931,  874], dtype=np.float64)

a+0.1-a
# array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1])

((a+0.1-a)-0.1) / 0.1
# array([  2.27318164e-13,   2.27318164e-13,   2.27318164e-13])
```

Using `np.array((0.1,)*3)` in the middle of the expression turned everything to `float64`, which explains the higher precision in the second result.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I haven't seen the implicit 64-bit type! I understand that numpy cannot just take 64 bit in ``a+0.1-a`` without being instructed to do so.